# How to remove blue color from hyperlink in a button

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink

I am working on a html email, where I have a green button and therefore I need to remove the blue color from the hyperlink in the button.

I have tried EVERTHING... !important; - text-decoration:none; a:active, a:focus,  - you name it..

So is there a helpful person out there, who can help me with this issue, my code relating to the button is currently as follows:

```
/* What it does: Hover styles for buttons */

        .button-td,
        .button-a {
            transition: all 100ms ease-in;
            color: #ffffff !important;
        }

        .button-td:hover,
        .button-a:hover {
            background: rbg(1,84,61);opacity: 0.8; !important;
            border-color: rbg(1,84,61);opacity: 0.8; !important;
            
        }

<!-- Button : Begin -->

</p>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="center-on-narrow" style="float:center;">
<tr>
<td style="border-radius: 3px; background: #01553d; text-align: center;" class="button-td"><a style="background: #01553d; border: 15px solid #01553d; padding: 0 10px; color: #ffffff !important; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.1; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;" href="^slink^" class="button-a"> 
<font color="#FFFFFF"></font>
<!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]-->^slink^<!--[if mso]>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]--> 
</a></td>
</tr>
</table>
                            
<!-- Button : END --></td>
```

Comment: This sounds like an issue with some specific email client insisting on rendering links in blue. You'll need to provide more information about your testing environment.

Answer (score 1):

Use `style="text-decoration:none;"`

Comment: To change the **colour**?!

Comment: … and the code in the question shows they are doing that already anyway.